# Change language in Visual Studio 1.72.2

Tags: visual-studio

How I can change the display language in Visual Studio 1.72.2?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2022 (which is Visual Studio v17), open the Visual Studio Installer, click the 'Modify' button for the installation you want to change, click 'Language Packs', and verify that the language you want is installed. If not installed, check the checkbox for the desired language pack, click the 'Modify' button to install, and follow the installer directions.

Back in Visual Studio, in the 'Tools' menu choose 'Options'. In 'Environment' -> 'International Settings' there should be a 'Language' drop-down menu for the installed language packs.

Answer (score 0):

There should be command named Configure Display Language. Hit ctrl+shift+p and type the command.

Comment: You may be thinking of Visual Studio *Code*, not Visual Studio. ctrl+shift+p opens the command palette in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Yes, I assumed the question is about VS Code based on version 1.72.2, which doesn't match to VS.